# click function after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hello I am working on a simple project using javascript, and I am trying to have a click event fired after the page posts back from the server, and I cant seem to figure out how to do it.  Here is my code below

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .SignUp
        {
            padding-right: 450px;
            padding-left: 25px;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }
        .auto-style1 
        {
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        .auto-style2
        {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .auto-style3 
        {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            width: 158px;
        }
        .Message
        {
            margin-left: 100px;
            margin-top: 75px;
        }
        </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <h1>Sign Up for an Account:</h1>
    <div class="SignUp">
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">First Name</td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" Class="FirstName" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Firstname" ErrorMessage="Please Enter First Name" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">Last Name</td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" class="LastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Last Name" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="LastName">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">Password</td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" class="Password" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Create a Password" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="Password">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">Confirm Password</td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" class="ConfirmPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Confirm Password" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" ErrorMessage="Passwords must Match" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">Email</td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Email" class="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="Please enter an Email" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="Please Enter a valid Email" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">ConfirmEmail</td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmEmail" class="ConfirmEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmEmail" ErrorMessage="Please confirm Email" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="Email" ControlToValidate="ConfirmEmail" ErrorMessage="Emails must Match" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
   </div>
    <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="CreateAccount" Class="CreateAccount" runat="server" Text="Create Account" OnClick="SignUp_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label  ID="Message" class="Message" runat="server" BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="30px" ForeColor="Red" Text="You have successfully created an Account" Height="30px" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:portfoliobrownConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [FirstName], [LastName], [Password], [ConfirmPassword], [ConfirmEmail], [Email] FROM [SignUP]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(".CreateAccount").click(function () {
           var first = document.getElementsByClassName("FirstName")
           var last = document.getElementsByClassName("LastName")
           var pass = document.getElementsByClassName("Password")
           var ConPass = document.getElementsByClassName("ConrirmPassword")
           var Email = document.getElementsByClassName("Email")
           var conEmail = document.getElementsByClassName("ConfirmEmail")
               if(first.length > 0 && last.length > 0 && pass.length > 0 && conPass.length > 0 &&
                   Email.length > 0 && conEnail.length > 0)
               {
                    alert("ehb");  
               }

           });
```

So basically I want the alert method to fire after the button is clicked on to create the account, but only when the page posts back from the server.

Thanks, any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have a mistyped error in your javascript first correct it. In your if condition you typed `conEnail`.

Comment: hey thanks a lot for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RegisterStartupScript` for that. Create a javascript function that handles the alert.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAlert(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
</script>
```

Then call that function from code behind.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = "Place message here";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "showAlert", "showAlert('" + message + "')", true);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much I have got it working, your code helped a lot.  Sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

You must check if input is empty or not. Give your input elements id tags like this:

```
<input id="username" ...
<input id="password" ...
```

Then check them logically in JS.

```
<script>
    function button_onclick(){
         var name = document.getElementById('<%= username.ClientID %>').value;
         var passw = document.getElementById('<%= password.ClientID %>').value;
         if(name.length > 0 && passw.length > 0){
            alert("Fields are not empty!");
         }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply. I actually want to show the alert box after the button has been clicked, and the page refreshes.  I have a form that needs to be filled out with required validators.  I can get the alert to work when the button is clicked but even if the form isn't filled out, and I want to prevent that.  I only want the alert box to appear once it is filled out and the page refreshes.  Hope that makes sence

Comment: Hey thanks for the input, but it didn't seem to work, and it may be because I am using server controls and not just html tags.  So instead of input its asp:textbox for all the textbox in the sign up form.  And getting element by I'd didn't work.  I even tried doing it by class name

Comment: Were you able to come up with a solution?

Comment: I updated my answer. `username.ClientID` should do the trick. If not, you can google it with "How to get asp net object values in JS?" query.